# how to write json back to the s3 in aws Glue?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, aws-glue

Iam new to the aws-glue. I am trying to read the csv and transforming to the json object. As i seen the approach would be to read the csv via crawler and convert to Pyspark DF, then convert to json object. 
Till now, i have converted to json object. Now i would need to write these json back to s3 bucket?

### Below is the code

```
#########################################
### IMPORT LIBRARIES AND SET VARIABLES
#########################################

#Import python modules
from datetime import datetime

#Import pyspark modules
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

#Import glue modules
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job
import json
import boto3

#Initialize contexts and session
spark_context = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glue_context = GlueContext(spark_context)
session = glue_context.spark_session
s3_source = boto3.resource('s3')

#Parameters
glue_db = "umesh-db"
glue_tbl = "read"

#########################################
### EXTRACT (READ DATA)
#########################################
#Read movie data to Glue dynamic frame
dynamic_frame_read = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = glue_db, table_name = glue_tbl)

#Convert dynamic frame to data frame to use standard pyspark functions
data_frame = dynamic_frame_read.toDF()

## Show DF data
print("Showing Df data")
data_frame.show()

### Convert the DF to the json
jsonContent = data_frame.toJSON()
jsonValue={}
arrraYObj=[]
for row in jsonContent.collect():
    print("Row data ", row)
    arrraYObj.append(row)
print("Array Obj",arrraYObj)
jsonValue['Employee']=arrraYObj
print("Json object ", jsonValue)

#Log end time
#dt_end = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#print("Start time:", dt_end)
```

Appreciate if anyone can help to provide the right approach?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data_frame.write.format(‘json’).save(‘s3://bucket/key’)
```

Or directly from dynamic frame

```
glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = dynamic_frame_read,
          connection_type = "s3",
          connection_options = {"path": "s3://bucket/key"},
          format = "json")
```

Comment: Hi Emerson.. I also would like to know does glue have event based trigger similar to lambda? or what would be the approach to process the glue job against the data when it uploaded in the target s3 bucket?

Comment: You will have to call the glue job from a step function or lambda, which can be triggered based on events

Comment: Ok Thank You Emerson